# Why is -1 sorted before -Infinity in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, sorting

Out of curiosity, what rules apply here exactly?

```
alert([-Infinity, -1, Infinity, 0, 1].sort());
```

Outputs: `-1, -Infinity, 0, 1, Infinity`

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/8tVGb/

---

How is it that -Infinity gets sorted between -1 and 0?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you don't use a custom compare function, [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) always converts the items to strings and orders them lexicographically. Use

```
….sort(function(a,b){ return a-b; })
```

See also [How to sort an array of integers correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1063007)

Comment: Just curious, but won't `-1 - -infinity` yield NaN, or -infinity or some other nonsensical result in JavaScript?  So for infinities and NaN's `a-b` is no good?

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey: Nope, `-1 - -Infinity` yields `Infinity` which *has* a sense - it's greater than zero so `b` should come before `a`. Infinities compare fine, only `NaN` would cause problems.

Comment: Whenever you're working with a language that has numberical overflow wrap-around (where `Integer.MAX + 1 == Integer.NEGATIVE_MIN`), @SoftwareMonkey is right. In those cases, this technique will always work: `sort(function(a, b){ return (a > b ? 1 : (a < b ? -1 : 0)) }`

Comment: @Kevin: OK, but JavaScript is not such a language :-)

Comment: Thanks for the precise answer :)